# How to remove User-Agent String when I make a http post call?

Tags: java, android, httprequest, okhttp, user-agent

I want to remove "User-Agent" property from my post httprequest.

I'm using okhttpclient.

Can anyone help me with snippet of code?

Comment: Any particular reason to not include User-agent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove it for any request the client sends.

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .addNetworkInterceptor(chain -> chain.proceed(chain.request().newBuilder()
          .removeHeader("user-agent")
          .build()))
      .build();
```